# How to retrieve accidental commits to a remote tracking branch?

Tags: git

According to [GitGuys](http://www.gitguys.com/topics/tracking-branches-and-remote-tracking-branches/)

> Remote Tracking Branches should not be modified by users (don’t set your git branch to a remote tracking branch via git checkout and then try to modify the remote tracking branch).

Unfortunately, that's exactly what I did by accident, and committed a day's work. And now after switching to a different branch, those commits have disappeard and cannot be found in the log of any existing branch, local or remote.

Fortunately, I still see them in .git/logs/HEAD and using `git show` with the hashes there gives me the code diffs, so they're not lost completely. My questions:

- How can I get those changes into a regular branch?
- If one should not commit to a remote tracking branch, why does it not result in an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commits are likely still there.  You just need to find a reference that points to them.

Use [`git reflog`](http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/05/git-tip-of-week-reflogs.html) to find your last commit that you lost.  Once you find that commit, use `git checkout -b <branch name> <lost commit hash>` to create and checkout a branch that points to that tip.

As far as the error, you should have received a message saying you were working in a headless state.